# difference between public and author in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I am trying to find out difference between public and author module in magnolia CMS.

I am trying to integrate spring mvc into magnolia using blossom.

Which module I need to use is it public or author module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need both author and public instance/environment. And you need to have blossom installed on both of them.

The author and public instances typically feature exactly same set of modules, but they are configured differently. You can have both configurations in one war file and let Magnolia discover at runtime which one to use. More in [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management).

Author instance is typically living in safety of your internal network, not exposed to public consumers in any way. This is the instance where your editors will prepare all the content for the website that they eventually want to make public. Once content is ready, editors will make it public by using "Publish" content action in the menu. This might trigger either direct publication of the content or workflow with some review or other steps depending on how you configure it.

Publication process will take the content and transfer it from the author environment to single or multiple public environments depending on your configuration and edition you are using. See [configuration of subscribers](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Subscribers) for more info on this.

Public environment is, opposite to author, living outside, exposed to everyone you want to be able to access your website powered by Magnolia. This is typically never accessed by editors and only rarely by admins and configured to limit access to anything that requires authorisation only from selected few locations. Anyway, the other major difference is that public instance is configured to serve the content as efficiently as possible with dedicating more resources to caches and so on. Typically the only way how this instance ever sees new content is via publication process.

Again more info on this can be found in [Magnolia's documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Instance+diagrams).